# Fixed div gets cut off inside overflow container

Tags: css, overflow, fixed

I am trying to make a fixed div to be on top of overflow container it is placed in. But seems that `transform` style set to `#container` causes issues.

Does anyone has solution for that?

Here's an example on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/no1lov3sme/3du07h2s/

Comment: A transform changes the containing element - so your fixed element is now fixed in relation to its parent. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359595/fixed-div-gets-cut-off-inside-overflow-container?noredirect=1#comment127832392_72359595) by [A Haworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867454/a-haworth).